# Can my use of paste0() in R be corrected so that this function runs as fast as the original Python example?

Tags: python, string, r

I am trying to play around with some R code I found recently that imitates parts of [Norvig's spell checker](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb) written in Python; In particular, I am trying to work out the right way to implement the `edit2` function in R:

```py
def splits(word):
    return [(word[:i], word[i:]) 
            for i in range(len(word)+1)]

def edits1(word):
    pairs      = splits(word)
    deletes    = [a+b[1:]           for (a, b) in pairs if b]
    transposes = [a+b[1]+b[0]+b[2:] for (a, b) in pairs if len(b) > 1]
    replaces   = [a+c+b[1:]         for (a, b) in pairs for c in alphabet if b]
    inserts    = [a+c+b             for (a, b) in pairs for c in alphabet]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

def edits2(word):
    return set(e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1))
```

However, in my benchmarks, it seems, generating thousands of small strings in R using `paste0` (or `str_c` from stringr, or `stri_join` from stringi) results in code that is roughly 10x (or ~100x, or ~50x) slower than the Python implementation shown by Norvig. (Yes, the stringr and stringi-based functions interestingly are *even slower* than using `paste0`.) My questions are (with #3 being the main one I want resolved):

1. Am I doing this correctly (is the code "right")?
2. If so, is this a known issue of R (extremely slow string concatenation)?
3. Is there anything I can do about this to make this **significantly** faster (one or more orders of magnitude, at least) **without** rewriting the whole function in Rcpp11 or something like that?

Here is my R code I came up with for the `edit2` function:

```
# 1. generate a list of all binary splits of a word
binary.splits <- function(w) {
  n <- nchar(w)
  lapply(0:n, function(x)
         c(stri_sub(w, 0, x), stri_sub(w, x + 1, n)))
}

# 2. generate a list of all bigrams for a word
bigram.unsafe <- function(word)
  sapply(2:nchar(word), function(i) substr(word, i-1, i))
bigram <- function(word)
  if (nchar(word) > 1) bigram.unsafe(word) else word

# 3. four edit types: deletion, transposition, replacement, and insertion
alphabet = letters
deletions <- function(splits) if (length(splits) > 1) {
   sapply(1:(length(splits)-1), function(i)
          paste0(splits[[i]][1], splits[[i+1]][2]), simplify=FALSE) 
} else {
    splits[[1]][2]
}   
transpositions <- function(splits) if (length(splits) > 2) {
  swaps <- rev(bigram.unsafe(stri_reverse(splits[[1]][2])))
  sapply(1:length(swaps), function(i)
         paste0(splits[[i]][1], swaps[i], splits[[i+2]][2]), simplify=FALSE)
} else {
  stri_reverse(splits[[1]][2])
} 
replacements <- function(splits) if (length(splits) > 1) {
  sapply(1:(length(splits)-1), function(i)
         lapply(alphabet, function(symbol)
                paste0(splits[[i]][1], symbol, splits[[i+1]][2])))
} else {
  alphabet
} 
insertions <- function(splits)
  sapply(splits, function(pair)
         lapply(alphabet, function(symbol)
                paste0(pair[1], symbol, pair[2]))) 

# 4. create a vector of all words at edit distance 1 given the input word
edit.1 <- function(word) {
  splits <- binary.splits(word)
  unique(unlist(c(deletions(splits),
                  transpositions(splits),
                  replacements(splits),
                  insertions(splits))))
}

# 5. create a simple function to generate all words of edit distance 1 and 2
edit.2 <- function(word) { 
  e1 <- edit.1(word)
  unique(c(unlist(lapply(e1, edit.1)), e1))
}
```

If you start profiling this code, you will see that `replacements` and `insertions` have nested "lapplies" and seem to take 10x longer than the `deletions` or `transpositions`, because they generate far more spelling variants.

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(edit.2('abcd'), replications=20)
```

This takes about 8 seconds on my Core i5 MacBook Air, while the corresponding Python benchmark (running the corresponding `edit2` function 20 times) takes about 0.6 seconds, i.e., it is about 10-15 times faster!

I have tried using `expand.grid` to get rid of the inner `lapply`, but this made the code slower, not faster. And I know that using `lapply` in place of `sapply` makes my code a bit faster, but I do not see the point of using the "wrong" function (I want a vector back) for a minor speed bump. But maybe generating the result of the `edit.2` function can be made much faster **in pure R**?

Comment: I might answer the R part of your title with something like `x = y = sample(letters, 1e7, TRUE); system.time(paste(x, y))` how would I measure the equivalent in python?

Comment: Since you seem to have been willing to at least try to use the `stringi` package, is there a reason you're limiting answers to **pure R** (many/most of the `stringi` functions are C++-backed)?

Comment: @MartinMorgan - no need to compare or use Python; I just want to know if there is a way in R to write a version of the edit.2 function I show that is 10x faster than the version above (and, therefore, equivalent to a Python and a few other dynamic languages).

Comment: @hrbrmstr - You are free to use any regular CRAN packages (stringi included); The thing I am not interested is learning how to implement `edit.2` in C++ - if needed, I could do that myself. I want to learn if there is an efficient way to work with strings in ("pure") R (including popular R packages on CRAN).

Comment: The current implementation of `paste0` has a lot of overhead for scalar use.But R is oriented towards vector processing, so you can speed things up by taking a more vector based approach. For your inner loop in `insertions` you can use `paste0(pair[1], alphabet, pair[2])`, and similar in the others. To vectorize in more places you can return a more vectorization friendly data structure from `binary.split`, e.g. a pair of vectors instead of a list of pairs.

Comment: @LukeTierney I understand my R codes is bad? I somehow was hoping for that! So does this mean there is a way to make my code 10x faster, too? I will try fuddling around with `binary.split()`, then.

Comment: @LukeTierney I just tried your tip about `insertions` and that indeed already made the code >3x faster. I will now try to resolve `binary.split` issues. Thanks! You probably should paste your comment as an answer (i.e., if generating vectors from `binary.split` helps for the other factor of 3 speedup amiss).

Comment: Re. Luke's tips: I now changed `binary.split` to return two vectors and got rid of the apply calls in `deletions` and `transpositions`, but the final improvement is still only a factor of 5x, i.e., the R version of `edit.2` is still only runs at less than half the speed of the Python version. I'll add the changes into my question.

Comment: Could you post the answer as an answer rather than as part of your question?

Comment: @BenBolker Should I attach the final solution to the partial answer below? Is it "politically correct" for me to edit Martin's answer? I was trying to give Martin at least some "reputation" for his efforts. Or should I open a new answer and tag that as correct (but, then, Martin would loose the reputation...) And how about Luke, who actually should receive the credit of answering my question, but did so only in a comment? It seems you are an SO expert, so please let me know how to correctly handle this conundrum...

Comment: I think it's fine to just post your final solution as a separate answer; it's common for there to be more than one useful answer to a question. I appreciate your concern for giving credit to Martin and Luke.

Comment: @BenBolker: OK, done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Performance of R's paste0 vs. python's ''.join

The original title asked whether paste0 in R was 10x slower than string concatenation in python. If it is, then there's no hope of writing an algorithm that relies heavily on string concatenation in R that is as fast as the corresponding python algorithm.

I have

```
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.0 Patched (2014-05-31 r65803)"
```

and

```
>>> sys.version '3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'
```

Here's a first comparison

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(paste0("a", "b"), times=1e6)
Unit: nanoseconds
             expr min   lq median   uq      max neval
 paste0("a", "b") 951 1071   1162 1293 21794972 1e+06
```

(so about 1s for all replicates) versus

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("''.join(x)", "x=('a', 'b')", number=int(1e6))
0.119668865998392
```

I guess that's the 10x performance difference the original poster observed. 
However, R works better on vectors, and the algorithm involves vectors
of words anyway, so we might be interested in the comparison

```
> x = y = sample(LETTERS, 1e7, TRUE); system.time(z <- paste0(x, y))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.479   0.009   1.488
```

and

```
>>> setup = '''
import random
import string
y = x = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(10000000)]
'''
>>> timeit.Timer("map(''.join, zip(x, y))", setup=setup).repeat(1)
[0.362522566007101]
```

This suggests that we would be on the right track if our R algorithm
were to run at 1/4 the speed of python; the OP found a 10-fold
difference, so it looks like there's room for improvement.

### R iteration versus vectorization

The OP uses iteration (`lapply` and friends), rather than vectorization. We can compare the vector version to various approaches to iteration with the following

```
f0 = paste0

f1 = function(x, y) 
   vapply(seq_along(x), function(i, x, y) paste0(x[i], y[i]), character(1), x, y)

f2 = function(x, y) Map(paste0, x, y)

f3 = function(x, y) {
    z = character(length(x))
    for (i in seq_along(x)) 
        z[i] = paste0(x[i], y[i])
    z 
}

f3c = compiler::cmpfun(f3)    # explicitly compile

f4 = function(x, y) {
    z = character()
    for (i in seq_along(x)) 
        z[i] = paste0(x[i], y[i])
    z 
}
```

Scaling the data back, defining the 'vectorized' solution as f0, and
comparing these approaches

```
> x = y = sample(LETTERS, 100000, TRUE)
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f0(x, y), f1(x, y), f2(x, y), f3(x, y), f3c(x, y), times=5)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
  f0(x, y)  14.69877  14.70235  14.75409  14.98777  15.14739     5
  f1(x, y) 241.34212 250.19018 268.21613 279.01582 292.21065     5
  f2(x, y) 198.74594 199.07489 214.79558 229.50684 271.77853     5
  f3(x, y) 250.64388 251.88353 256.09757 280.04688 296.29095     5
 f3c(x, y) 174.15546 175.46522 200.09589 201.18543 214.18290     5
```

with `f4` being too painfully slow to include

```
> system.time(f4(x, y))
   user  system elapsed 
 24.325   0.000  24.330
```

So from this one can see the advice from Dr. Tierney, that there may be a benefit to vectorizing those `lapply` calls.

### Further vectorizing the updated original post

@fnl adopted the original code by partly unrolling the loops. There remain opportunities for more of the same, for instance,

```
replacements <- function(splits) if (length(splits$left) > 1) {
  lapply(1:(length(splits$left)-1), function(i)
         paste0(splits$left[i], alphabet, splits$right[i+1]))
} else {
  splits$right[1]
}
```

might be revised to perform a single paste call, relying on argument recycling (short vectors recycled until their length matches longer vectors)

```
replacements1 <- function(splits) if (length(splits$left) > 1) {
    len <- length(splits$left)
    paste0(splits$left[-len], rep(alphabet, each = len - 1), splits$right[-1])
} else {
  splits$right[1]
}
```

The values are in different order, but that is not important for the algorithm. Dropping subscripts (prefix with -) is potentially more memory efficient. Similiarly

```
deletions1 <- function(splits) if (length(splits$left) > 1) {
  paste0(splits$left[-length(splits$left)], splits$right[-1])
} else {
  splits$right[1]
}

insertions1 <- function(splits)
    paste0(splits$left, rep(alphabet, each=length(splits$left)), splits$right)
```

We then have

```
edit.1.1 <- function(word) {
  splits <- binary.splits(word)
  unique(c(deletions1(splits),
           transpositions(splits),
           replacements1(splits),
           insertions1(splits)))
}
```

with some speed-up

```
> identical(sort(edit.1("word")), sort(edit.1.1("word")))
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(edit.1("word"), edit.1.1("word"))
Unit: microseconds
             expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
   edit.1("word") 354.125 358.7635 362.5260 372.9185 521.337   100
 edit.1.1("word") 296.575 298.9830 300.8305 307.3725 369.419   100
```

The OP indicates that their original version was 10x slower than
python, and that their original modifications resulted in a 5x
speed-up. We gain a further 1.2x speed-up, so are perhaps at the
expected performance of the algorithm using R's paste0. A next step is to ask whether alternative algorithms or implementations are more performant, in particular `substr` might be promising.

Comment: If you are in python 2.X, ``range`` produces a list, which is very slow for large list sizes. Use ``xrange`` for a more accurate comparison

Comment: You are comparing R's `paste0()` versus the worst possible way of concatenating Strings in Python: **never ever** concatenate Strings in Python using the + operator, this is known to be several times slower than `"".join()` or using a Sting buffer (thus, proving my point, anyways). Furthermore, again, I am not interested in artificial microbenchmarks, I want to see results on real-world problems. So my question (make the very real-word `edit.2` function ~10x faster) remains unsolved.

Comment: @fnl As I say in my answer I don't know how to program python, so I'll update my answer with my best guess about your hint, thanks. if you're not interested in the speed of R's paste versus python, then change your title, but the reason for focusing on the basic operation is that if string concatenation in R _were_ 10x slower, and most of your program is concatenating strings, then you couldn't write an R program that was the same speed as python!

Comment: The Python code you are using is still sub-optimal (as you see, what you just tried above even made it worse...) - please don't try to "invent" microbenchmarks in a language you don't know. Furthermore, Luke did correctly answer my actual question(s) in the comments, so unless he pastes the answer to get the credit, this question will have to stay "unanswered".

Comment: I have adjusted to title to reflect what my real issue/problem is/was.

Comment: @fnl If Luke does not post an answer consider posting your revised code as an answer, while acknowledging him.  I, for one, would be interested in seeing the revised code.

Comment: FYI, Martin, here is the right way to do your micro-"benchmark" in Python: `import timeit; timeit.timeit("''.join(x)", "x=('a', 'b')", number=int(1e7))`. This is nearly twice as fast as the R version you show in the beginning of your post. But, as said, please just "ask Google" about how ridiculous comparing languages with micro-benchmarks is...

Comment: @MarkMiller Done - I've updated my question with the revised code; The problem is I am still only half way to the speed of the Python version... There must be a solution, right? The only thing that really irks me so far is how sensitive R code is to even the slightest deviation from "optimal"...

Answer (score 1):

Following @LukeTierney's tips in the question's comments on vecotrizing `paste0` calls and returning two vectors `binary.splits`, I edited the functions to be correctly vectorized. I have added the additional modifications as described by @MartinMorgan in his answer, too: dropping items using single suffixes instead of using selection ranges (i.e., `"[-1]"` instead of `"[2:n]"`, etc.; but NB: for multiple suffixes, as used in `transpositions`, this is actually slower) and, particularly, using `rep` to further vectorize the `paste0` calls in `replacements` and `insertions`.

This results in the best possible answer (so far?) to implement `edit.2` in R (thank you, Luke and Martin!). In other words, with the main hints provided by Luke and some subsequent improvements by Martin, the R implementation ends up roughly half as fast as Python (but see Martin's final comments in his answer below). (The functions `edit.1`, `edit.2`, and `bigram.unsafe` remain unchanged, as shown above.)

```
binary.splits <- function(w) {
  n <- nchar(w)
  list(left=stri_sub(w, rep(0, n + 1), 0:n),
       right=stri_sub(w, 1:(n + 1), rep(n, n + 1)))
}

deletions <- function(splits) {
  n <- length(splits$left)
  if (n > 1) paste0(splits$left[-n], splits$right[-1])
  else splits$right[1]
}
transpositions <- function(splits) if (length(splits$left) > 2) {
  swaps <- rev(bigram.unsafe(stri_reverse(splits$right[1])))
  paste0(splits$left[1:length(swaps)], swaps,
         splits$right[3:length(splits$right)])
} else {
  stri_reverse(splits$right[1])
}
replacements <- function(splits) {
  n <- length(splits$left)
  if (n > 1) paste0(splits$left[-n],
                    rep(alphabet, each=n-1),
                    splits$right[-1])
  else alphabet
}
insertions <- function(splits)
  paste0(splits$left,
         rep(alphabet, each=length(splits$left)),
         splits$right)
```

Overall, and to conclude this exercise, Luke's and Martin's suggestions made the R implementation run roughly half as fast as the Python code shown in the beginning, improving my original code by about a factor of 6. What worries me even more in the end, however, are two different issues: (1) The R code seems to be far more verbose (LOC, but might be polished up a bit) and (2) the fact that even a slight deviation from "correct vectorization" makes R code perform horrible, while in Python slight deviations from "correct Python" *usually* do not have such an extreme impact. Nonetheless, I'll keep on with my "coding *efficient* R" effort - thanks to everybody involved!